# Simple comparing throw wrong result Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-component, vuetify.js

I've got 2  components in a modal.

The first:

```
              <v-text-field
          label="Limite de faltantes"
          type="number"
          v-model="lim_faltProd"
          ></v-text-field>
```

The second:

```
          <v-text-field
          label="Limite de excedentes"
          type="number"
          v-model="lim_excProd"
          ></v-text-field>
```

My component export:

```
export default {
  props: ['nombre', 'precio', 'lim_falt', 'lim_exc', 'id'],
  data () {
    return {
      error: '',
      idProd: this.id,
      nombreProd: this.nombre,
      precioProd: this.precio,
      lim_faltProd: this.lim_falt,
      lim_excProd: this.lim_exc
    }
  },
  watch: {
    nombre () {
      this.nombreProd = this.nombre
    },
    precio () {
      this.precioProd = this.precio
    },
    lim_falt () {
      this.lim_faltProd = this.lim_falt
    },
    lim_exc () {
      this.lim_excProd = this.lim_exc
    },
    id () {
      this.idProd = this.id
    }
}
```

So when i try to do such a simple thing like

> this.lim_faltProd >= this.lim_excProd

It gets crazy.

Look at this, I get

> console.log(this.lim_faltProd) //  20
>
> console.log(this.lim_excProd)  // 100
>
> console.log(this.lim_faltProd >= this.lim_excProd) // THROWS TRUE!!!!

---

---

I'll show it:
**I've a function where I do:**

```
     async registrarProducto () {
this.error = this.lim_faltProd > this.lim_excProd
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing Strings; `"20"` is larger than `"100"` because `"2"` is larger than `"1"` (the first character). Convert them to *Number* if you want to compare the numeric value:

```
this.error = Number(this.lim_faltProd) >= Number(this.lim_excProd)
```

```js
console.log("20" >= "100")

console.log(Number("20") >= Number("100"))
```

Comment: So if i want to do it in a `if`, i MUST use `Number()` too?

Comment: If you want to compare the two values in a numeric sense, you need to use `Number`. Doesn't matter where you do it as long as it's still in javascript.

Comment: Thank you! i'll flag this as solved. Is there any way to store directly the value number and not to store it as strings?.

Comment: You can do the conversion when your first initialize your data. i.e. in `data ()` `lim_faltProd: Number(this.lim_falt),
      lim_excProd: Number(this.lim_exc)` You can also check [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) and see how to declare your `props` with specific types.